# Object created from Sapling addon not exported properly to FBX

Tags: mesh, export, sapling-addon

I just made a tree in blender, with the sapling add-on, for my unreal engine 4 game. I exported the mesh and i imported to the unreal engine 4.. there are no textures imported and it looks something like the picture -.- HUGE leaves and a normal size tree in different places... also in the unreal engine 4 log it says that it must be something with my exporting in blender.. anyone know how to help?[image: this is the distance between the leaves and the tree.. also they are 1 object so i cant move the leave in to the tree and scale them down..(tree is that little thing in the left side of the picture.. also the tree is in the normal scale but the leaves are 100 times bigger than they should be :D]
[image: this is how the tree supposed to be :P]

Comment: yes they were.. I re-applyed them and then re-exported the mesh and imported it into ue4 and still the same..

Comment: are the leaves parented to the tree? If so, try `Alt` `P` > *Clear and Keep Transform*.

Comment: @David I dont have them parented .. i managed to upload them by transforming the curve into a mesh.. now i have the texture problem only.. they are coming in unreal engine all gray :P i need to find a way to "bake" or "attach" the texture into the mesh :D  if you could help in this one it would be nice :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem after an hour of work :D The sapling add-on wasnt creating meshes.. it was creating curves..  So i tranformed the the curver into a mesh and the i exported it and it was done :D